# Excel VBA: Sheet protection not working as desired

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA I'm trying to disallow insertion and deletion of rows and columns while allowing the user to edit cell contents. I was hoping the following call would do the trick:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SomePassword", _
AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, Contents:=False
```

But this doesn't work as I expect. I can still insert and delete rows and columns.

What am I missing? What's the correct way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after a little more experimentation. Here's the code:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SomePassword"
```

This sets the 'Locked' property of all cells in the sheet to 'False' and then protects the sheet fully. The reason it works is because protection disables editing *only* for those cells that have 'Locked' set to 'True'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you need `Contents:=True` in order for everything else to work! Of course, this goes against your need for users to be able to edit the content of cells... locked cells, that is. So just unlock all your cells (Format|Protection|uncheck the Locked tickbox) prior to protecting the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that AllowInsertingRows etc. are options that are only available if you lock down the contents with Contents:=True. This is not made clear in the Help information.

As you want contents to be editable, you're have to mark all cells that you want editable as unlocked (set cell or range property Locked to false). Then use Protect with Contents:=True.