# Worksheet.Protect AllowDeletingRows does not allow deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook I'm protecting all sheets on Workbook_Open, with the following code:

```vb
ws.Protect Password:="password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
```

In the last line I specifically turn on AllowDeletingRows to allow the user to delete rows. Inserting rows works just fine, but if I try to delete a row on the protected sheet Excel tells me I can't delete rows that contain locked cells. Does anyone know how to get AllowDeletingRows working properly?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5620902/9758194). Not an answer, but related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.protection.allowdeletingrows):

> [...]
>   The rows containing the cells to be deleted must be **unlocked** when the sheet is **protected**.

This means that when the `Sheet` is protected, you have to unlock the `Rows` first if you want to delete them.

### Example

In this example you can delete the first `Row` (following the first line) or the entire `Sheet` (following the second line) by unlocking it.

```
Sub ProtectionOptions() 
   'Unlock only row 1. 
   Rows("1:1").Locked = False

   'Or Unlock all cells. 
   Cells.Locked = False  

End Sub
```

### Edit

This `Sub` allows you to ask the user for which Row to delete and you can set `AllowDeletingRows:=False`, since you'll not be using the Excel `Delete` function. Here's the code:

```
Sub Setup()
    ws.Protect Password:="password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=False
End Sub

'Connect this Sub to a button.
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim userInput As String
    Dim row As Long

    userInput = InputBox("Please enter the row number you want to delete:", "Delete Row")
    If Not IsNumeric(userInput) Then
        MsgBox "Provided input is not numeric. Please insert a valid row number", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    row = userInput

    ws.rows(row).Locked = False
    ws.rows(row).Delete

End Sub
```

> **Note**: This code is tested and it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It means you have to unlock the cells of the row which is to be deleted, as shown in the example later in the documentation¨'

Comment: "This means that when the Sheet is protected, you have to unlock it first if you want to delete a Row." This is not what the documentation says

Comment: But if I unlock a row its protection is lost, right? So I can't just unlock the rows for the users.

Comment: @M.Schalk Yes, if you unlock a `Row` then it'll lose its protection. If you know which rows you want to delete, then you can unlock them right away, otherwise you have to use a Macro.

Comment: @Louis Hm ok, then this won't work with what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I need the user to be able to delete a row that contains protected cells while keeping the cells' protection intact until they are supposed to be deleted.

Comment: @M.Schalk This can be achieved by a Macro that asks the user which row he wants to delete. If you're interested I can show you the code editing the answer.

Comment: @Louis That would be interesting, thanks! What does the AllowDeletingRows property even do then?

Comment: @M.Schalk `AllowDeletingRows` simply enable/disable the action "Delete" when you right click on a row on the desidered `Sheet`. I'll post you the code.

Comment: @Louis Ah I see, still feels like a useless property then, since I won't be able to delete any rows if I protect the whole sheet but oh well. I guess there might be some niche use cases for that.

Comment: @M.Schalk Done. Let me know if this was useful and consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was. :)