# Excel conflict between locked cells and row deletion

Tags: excel, vba

This is a continuation from a previous discussion ([Worksheet.Protect AllowDeletingRows does not allow deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971314/worksheet-protect-allowdeletingrows-does-not-allow-deleting-rows)).  I was unable to comment there, hence this post.

In a nutshell, the problem is the need to lock specific cells/columns, whilst also allowing the end-user to delete rows (even though the rows contain locked cells).  These two requirements seem to be mutually exclusive outside of using VBA.

The following solution was suggested by @Louis on the above-referenced thread:

```
Sub Setup()
    ws.Protect Password:="password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=False
End Sub

'Connect this Sub to a button.
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim userInput As String
    Dim row As Long

    userInput = InputBox("Please enter the row number you want to delete:", "Delete Row")
    If Not IsNumeric(userInput) Then
        MsgBox "Provided input is not numeric. Please insert a valid row number", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    row = userInput

    ws.rows(row).Locked = False
    ws.rows(row).Delete

End Sub
```

I attempted to run this code, however after entering the desired row number in the pop-up box, I received an error message stating, "Run-time error '424': Object required". Using the debugger at this point shows highlighting on the line "ws.rows(row).Locked = False".

It's been years since I've attempted any VBA coding so I'm unsure how to proceed. Also, ideally it would be helpful to delete a range of rows (e.g., rows 7-103 or 150-200) at one sweep rather than line-by-line.

Any suggestions on how this might be accomplished, either by modifying the above code or via another method?

Comment: What is `ws` in your posted code?  It's neither declared not assigned in either of those two subs.  If it's a worksheet object, where is it coming from?

Comment: Good question and due to my years-long absence from VBA, I didn't pick up on that in the code I found in the other thread.  I interpreted "ws.rows(row).Locked = False" as an action that would unlock the cells within the entered row number in order for that row to be deleted.

Comment: It would do that but you need to give it a worksheet object (which is ws here I guess) or use `ActiveSheet.rows(row).Locked = False` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow the user to select the row(s) for deletion before running something like this:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    With Selection.EntireRow
        .Locked = False
        .Delete
    End With  
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion (on a worksheet with a few specific columns locked).  I selected 3 specific rows for deletion and then ran the macro.  I received the error message "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class."

Comment: I didn't test the unlock/delete approach.  The typical way to handle this type of thing is to unprotect the sheet, do whatever you need to do, then reprotect it.

Comment: Agreed, but in this case that's impractical due to the (un)reliability of the end-user who will be performing the deletions. It would be highly likely this user would unlock the sheet, then inadvertently type over or erase some of the formulae within the locked columns at some random points on the sheet, thus rendering the rest of the worksheet unusable.  This is why I'm hoping to have the unlocking/relocking coded in rather than having the user attempt to unlock/relock.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I mean you perform the unprotect/reprotect in your code, not that the user does it.  Your protection though has `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` so it should not prevent you doing anything via code...    https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm

Comment: Sorry for my misinterpretation, Tim; I understand what you meant now.  Your guidance has allowed me to solve this problem.  Much appreciated!  Also, I hadn't encountered OzGrid before, but it's an excellent resource which I'll use in the future.

Comment: Tim: I did attempt to upvote your answer, however due to my limited participation here my vote didn't change the reflected total, although apparently my vote is still recorded behind the scenes. Again, thank you!